# LIBGDX Tiled Map not using transparency

Tags: java, android, libgdx, transparency

I'm trying to draw trees on top of snow in a tiled map. However, when I draw my player sprite underneath the trees, the trees are not transparent and the sprite goes underneath white bits. I have added a transparency channel for the trees in gimp. I am using:

```
tiledMapRenderer.setView(cam);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
```

I have tried using

```
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and `batch.enableBlending();` to no prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the follwing:

1. Does your image file correctly define the transparency? (easy: check with any
   image viewer)
2. Do you load your image into a Texture object that supports alpha?
   (easy: use default Texture constructor with FileHandle)
3. Make sure all SpriteBatches you are using allow blending. (It's
   enabled by default and you did check that too)
4. Are you drawing the image into a FrameBuffer? Make sure your
   FrameBuffer has an alpha channel. Also check how you are clearing the FrameBuffer before use - if you are using intermediate FrameBuffers, eventually you should clear them to be transparent (blank).

Comment: I've gone through your steps except number two. The think is i'm not really sure how the file is being loaded. I'm using the software 'Tiled' and when I put the .tmx file into eclipse, I assume it loads all the information from there behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, apparently gimp didn't keep the transparency after I exported it to png, so I used ms paint and it is now transparent.

Comment: Great that you got it working! Gimp definitly can do that too - take a close look at the export options dialogs, there should be a setting somewhere to save png with alpha channel (for transparency).

Comment: Btw, my answer was correct, was it? Your issue has been #1 :-)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. I have marked your answer as correct.

Comment: It is rather hard to not get transparency in an exported file if you got it in a GIMP image already - any idea how you managed to do this?

Comment: I think I was ticking the box- use background color when exporting from Gimp.